# SubSonic 3.0 and Substage

Tags: subsonic

with the new version 3.0, can i use Substage and the old-fashion config settings or i move to use only T4 templates ?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Substage anymore or the old config settings (apart from a connection string of course) because the t4 templates do the code gen for you.

Have a look at the docs for a quickstart video:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page